# Backbone.js - Not able to trigger an event in a collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and Backbone and I came across this error.

```
Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        ":albumID": "load"

    },

    load: function (albumID) {
        if (controller.collectionInitialized == true) {
            console.log("RESET");
            album.trigger("clear");
        }

        var album = new Album([], {
            title: albumID
        });

        controller.trigger("collectionInit");
        controller.trigger("switchAlbum", albumID);
    }
});

Controller = Backbone.Model.extend({

    currentAlbum: "",
    collectionInitialized: false,

    initialize: function () {
        console.log("controller is initialized");
        this.on("switchAlbum", function (newAlbum) {
            this.currentAlbum = newAlbum;

        });

        this.on("collectionInit", function () {
            this.collectionInitialized = true;
        });
    }
});

Album = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    initialize: function (models, options) {
        this.on("clear", this.clear);
    },
    clear: function () {
        this.reset();
        this.off();
    }

});
```

I get this error: `Unable to get property 'trigger' of undefined or null reference`. The `if` statement makes sure that `album` already exists before triggering `clear`. Previously I tried just calling `album.reset()` directly but got the same error. My guess is that it's some kind of scoping problem, could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT

Re-reading the code, assuming `controller` is a valid instance and exists, and assuming that the `controller.collectionInitialized` is set to true, you are basically calling a method `trigger` on a variable `album` whose value is null.

Using JS hoisting rules, your load function could have be written as

```
load: function(albumID) {

    var album = null;

    if (controller.collectionInitialized == true) {
        console.log("RESET");
        album.trigger("clear");
    }

    album = new Album([], { title: albumID });
    controller.trigger("collectionInit");
    controller.trigger("switchAlbum", albumID);
}
```

Maybe, the above re-writing makes it clear that even if `controller.collectionInitialized` is `true`, `album` is a local variable and is always reset to null each time the load function is called.

What ever mechanism you used to enable global access to `controller`, use the same means to enable global access to `album`. Do not re-declare `album` as local to the function.

...

It may help to read more about [Javascript variable and function hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's true that in Javascript variables are `function-scoped`, meaning they're visible all over their local scope (i.e. the function host), but instantiation is a different beast.

```
load: function (albumID) {

    if (controller.collectionInitialized == true) {
        console.log("RESET");
        album.trigger("clear");
    }

    var album = new Album([], {
        title: albumID
    });

    controller.trigger("collectionInit");
    controller.trigger("switchAlbum", albumID);
}
```

You create a `new Album` *after* you call method `trigger` on album, thus resulting in a null reference.

Also, even if you call the function twice (i.e the first time having`controller.collectionInitialized` as `false`, and the second time as `true`), since the variable `album` is local to the function it's always undefined when you enter the `if` body, because its scope is the function `load`, so it "*dies*" every time the end of `load`'s body is reached.

[**Amith George**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16447144/1376657) provides the correct solution to your problem: define the variable `album` at one scope level higher (i.e. the level of the object you pass as argument to the `extend` method)

Comment: But the if statement makes sure that it only triggers `clear` if `album` has already been created. Does that not matter?

Comment: @DimaShabatin Actually I answered based on what I know about Javascript (I dont' happen to have used Backbone, yet). Where do you define `collectionInit` and `collectionInitialized`?